# Why does one of my AS3 event handlers only work once?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am building an SWF panel with support for English and Japanese, and a button to toggle between them. The English is on frame 1, the Japanese on frame 2. On the first frame there is this relevant AS3:

```
btnLangToggle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLangToggle);
```

...

```
this.stop();
```

...

```
function onLangToggle(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (MovieClip(root).currentFrame == 1) {
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);
    } else {
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    trace(MovieClip(root).currentFrameLabel);
}
```

I click the button and the event handler function runs fine, once. If I click it again, nothing happens. Why?

Edit: Here is what my two frames and timeline look like.

[image: English and Japanese UI]

[image: Timeline]

Comment: Is your script available in both frames 1 and 2. How does your timeline look like ?

Comment: I've updated the question with images of the two frames and the timeline.

Comment: Tha is really strange... does the same button instance exista also in both frames 1 and 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

> If I click it again, nothing happens. Why?

Because It's a MovieClip and they are designed for animation, not for application states. Objects on the scene in first frame isn't accessible in the second key frame.

I assume in your case you have button for toggling language with different instances of MovieClip(Different languages). In second frame apply again event listener for the Japanese version of the language button:

```
btnLangToggle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLangToggle);
```

Also, please read about [Document Class](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_document_class.html), It's pretty simple create application with only 2 states, like you have (with 2 frames...)

Comment: I rephrased my message

Comment: Actually, I am not using separate movie clips. I placed all my components on the main timeline. The components are all on a single layer, and this layer has keyframes on frames 1 and 2. I changed the labels on the required components on frame 2. The actionscript has a blank keyframe containing all the code on frame 1, and no other keyframes. I will look into the Document class however.

Comment: I've updated the question with images of my two frames, and the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using key frames for the button, right?
You must be sure that the button is the same on both frames. Which means you must not use key frames - instead use separate layer for the button with a single keyframe and two normal frames. This way your code will work as it's the same button.